# Create and Append an element, innerHTML? the horror... [please no jquery]

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid, outerhtml

I have a script that returns a list in alphabetical order as follows

```
<div id="x">
    <ul>
        <li>Apple
        <li>Banana
        <li>Blackberry
        <li>Blueberry
        <li>Cherry
        <li>Cranberry
    </ul>
</div>
```

However there are many items (almost 100) in the list and I am hoping to rearrange them as follows

```
<div id="x">
    <span id="A">A</span>
    <ul>
        <li>Apple
    </ul>
    <span id="B">B</span>
    <ul>
        <li>Banana
        <li>Blackberry
        <li>Blueberry
    </ul>
    <span id="C">C</span>
    <ul>
        <li>Cherry
        <li>Cranberry
    </ul>     
<div>
```

I'm not really sorting fruit btw, this is just an example.
It MUST be in that form, for reasons that matter not, I just need help creating and appending the span elements and the individual lists.
I have tried using inner/outer HTML and I'm finding it really really difficult. I currently have something like this:

```
function getAllLists()  
{  
var page = document.getElementById("x")
var allLists = page.getElementsByTagName("li");   
var num = allLists.length;  
//Some form of a for counter loop here
for (var counter = 0; counter < num; counter++) {   
    var first=allLists[counter].outerHTML;
    var second=allLists[counter+1].outerHTML;
    var firstletter= (allLists[counter].substring(0, 1)).toUpperCase();
    var secondletter= (allLists[counter+1].substring(0, 1)).toUpperCase();
    allLists[counter].outerHTML = '<span id="'+firstletter+'">'+firstletter+'</span>'+first;
    }
}
```

**PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE AVOID USING JQUERY.**
I can't stress this enough!!
Not only do I find it extremely difficult to understand, as I am still an amateur at javascript and find js already difficult enough as it is, the syntax for jquery is like just stupidly hard to understand.
I am certain it is possible to achieve what I am aiming for WITHOUT the need to use jquery.
Any ideas? all help/comments/ideas are more than appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: I think you might be missing the point of jQuery, it's not there to make things more difficult; most people should not really have to learn straight up javascript anymore these days.

Comment: @SLaks: It's valid - `<li>` elements do not need closing tags.

Comment: @SLaks—how? Looks fine to me. That comment should be removed.

Comment: @BoltClock uh really? it seems to work fine with chrome... i dont know. im just looking for method to achieve what i am hoping to achieve.@Godwin. I know jquery sounds amazing and is probably uber useful. but i am trying to grasp javascript first and then start looking into jquery.

Comment: @Vince Au: I dunno, I may be wrong about `outerHTML` :)

Comment: not closing `li` is totally fine but `span` is an inline element and should not wrapped around `li` that is block. Nice question though

Comment: @Mohsen, the `span` *isn't* wrapped around the `li` (or the `ul`)...

Comment: @BoltClock — [outerHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#outerhtml) is in HTML5, but not Firefox (and probably others) yet. One intention of HTML5 is to document what is in browsers, so the fact that it's there is really just documenting common current browser features and encourage others to follow suit.

Comment: @Godwin jQuery is there to give abstraction & normalization. It is _not_ there to avoid learning javascript. Please do not recommend that people use abstractions they dont understand

Answer (score 2):

Firstly forget all about manipulating the DOM using inner/outerHTML. They are handy for inserting chunks of HTML or sections of documents, but they are definitely not intended for general DOM manipulation.

Use DOM methods.

Firstly, load all the LI elements into an array. Then sort them using a sort function. Then put them back into the DOM wrapped in UL elements and separated by spans each time the first letter changes.

#### Edit

Here's a function that does the job. It sorts the lIs, not sure if that's really needed. If not, the function becomes a lot simpler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Simple helper
function getText(el) {
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  }
  if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  }
}

function sortLIs(id) {
  // Get the element
  var el = document.getElementById(id);

  // Get the UL element that will be replaced
  var sourceUl = el.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

  // Get the LIs and put them into an array for sorting
  var nodes = sourceUl.getElementsByTagName('li');
  var li, lis = [];

  for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    lis[i] = nodes[i];
  }

  // Sort them
  lis.sort(function(a, b) {
    return  getText(a) > getText(b)? 1 : -1;
  });

  // Now put them into the document in different ULs separated
  // by spans.
  // Create some temporary elements for cloning
  var ul, ulo = document.createElement('ul');
  var sp, spo = document.createElement('span');
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(); // fragments are handy
  var firstChar, currentChar;

  // For each LI in the array...
  for (i=0; i<iLen; i++) {
    li = lis[i];
    firstChar = getText(li).substr(0,1) || '';

    // If first char doesn't match current, create a new span
    // and UL for LIs
    if (firstChar !== currentChar) {
      currentChar = firstChar;

      // New span
      sp = spo.cloneNode(false);
      sp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstChar.toUpperCase()));
      sp.id = firstChar;
      frag.appendChild(sp);

      // New UL
      ul = ulo.cloneNode(false);
      frag.appendChild(ul);
    }

    // Add the li to the current ul
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  // Replace the UL in the document with the fragment
  el.replaceChild(frag, sourceUl);
}

</script>


<div id="x">
    <ul>
        <li>Cherry
        <li>Banana
        <li>Apple
        <li>Blueberry
        <li>Cranberry
        <li>Blackberry
    </ul>
</div>

<button onclick="sortLIs('x');">Sort</button>
```

Note that the LIs are just moved to the document fragment and that the original UL is replaced by multiple elements. I've jumbled the LIs to show that the sort works.

#### Edit 2

If you have the array as text, then:

```
var fruits = ['Cherry','Banana','Apple','Blueberry',
              'Cranberry','Blackberry'].sort();

function insertFruits(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);

  // Check that the above worked
  if (!el) return;

  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var li, lio = document.createElement('li');
  var ul, ulo = document.createElement('ul');
  var sp, spo = document.createElement('span');
  var firstChar, currentChar;

  for (var i=0, iLen=fruits.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    fruit = fruits[i];
    firstChar = fruit.substr(0,1).toUpperCase();

    if (firstChar !== currentChar) {
      currentChar = firstChar;
      sp = spo.cloneNode(false);
      sp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstChar));
      sp.id = firstChar;
      frag.appendChild(sp);
      ul = ulo.cloneNode(false);
      frag.appendChild(ul);
    }
    li = lio.cloneNode(false);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fruit));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  el.appendChild(frag);
}
```

Comment: I already have them in an array `allLists`, that is sorted in alphabetical order. I just have no idea how to pull out say all the ones starting with A, and put them into a `ul` of its own. thanks for a proper reply btw. :)

Comment: also im not too sure what DOM methods are... I've done a bit of research and I'm guessing it has something to do with creating and inserting elements? o.O still waiting for that example of yours. :S

Comment: If you already have the array and just wanted to put them in ULs, you should be able to get there from the code I posted. At the "insert LI" part, just create an LI and append the text (look at how it's done with the span elements).

Comment: Your first one worked tremendously. However, when I add it to my site, it refuses to work. =.=' I'll try harder. :S Thanks very much though! :)

Comment: Sorry, edited the first one and added `span.id = ...` instead of `sp.id = ...`. The error message should have told you that.

Comment: i didnt get an error message. :( and it still doesnt work. :( could you please try it in jsfiddle? maybe i am doing something wrong. thanks again for your help and your patience. :)

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="x">
    <ul>
        <li>Apple
        <li>Banana
        <li>Blackberry
        <li>Blueberry
        <li>Cherry
        <li>Cranberry
    </ul>
    <ul id="new"></ul>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var list = document.querySelector('#x ul'),
    newUl = document.getElementById('new'),
    fruits = [],
    key = "A";

for(var i=0; i<list.children.length; i++){
  fruits.push(list.children[i].innerText);
}

fruits.sort();

for(var i=0; i<fruits.length; i++){
  if(key == fruits[i].split('')[0]){
    var span = document.createElement('span'),
        li = document.createElement('li');
    span.setAttribute('id', key);
    li.innerText = fruits[i];
    if(document.getElementById(key)){
      document.getElementById(key).appendChild(li);
    }
    else{
      span.appendChild(li);
      newUl.appendChild(span);
    }

  }
  if(fruits[i+1]){
    key = fruits[i+1].split('')[0];
  }
}
```

#### Example:

**[Live Code](http://jsbin.com/ofukey/11/edit)**

Comment: innerText is not supported by some widely used browsers.

Comment: And neither is `document.querySelector()`.

Comment: `innerText` or `innerHTML` in this case is same. He can use `innerHTML`. Also if they want to use it they can do this: `innerText || textContent`. Not a big deal at all

Comment: @BoltClock We are here to answer the question not doing people's job. This answer the question asked above. Concept is important not those small details.
`querySelectors` are supported in IE8. I don't count IE7 as a *widely used browser*

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the way I get it done:

```
var allLists, elements, item, lastLetter, lastUl, letter, page, span, _i, _len;

page = document.getElementById("x");
allLists = page.getElementsByTagName("li");
lastLetter = null;
lastUl = null;
elements = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (_i = 0, _len = allLists.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  item = allLists[_i];
  letter = item.innerText[0].toUpperCase();
  if (letter !== lastLetter) {
    lastLetter = letter;
    span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = letter;
    span.id = letter;
    elements.appendChild(span);
    lastUl = document.createElement('ul');
    elements.appendChild(lastUl);
  }
  lastUl.appendChild(item.cloneNode(true));
}

while (page.firstChild) page.removeChild(page.firstChild);

page.appendChild(elements.cloneNode(true));
```

See this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/HjWhY/

Comment: Despite using jquery, your code does indeed work. However, the other reason why i despise using jquery is becauase it does not work with tumblr... Which is what I am doing all this for. but thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: Sorry, I only forgot to set no-library on sidebar, but my code doesn't need jQuery, it is "pure JS". ;)

Comment: But jsfiddle automatically loaded the jquery library for you. When I try to put it into a blank .html file or using html instant it doesnt run. :S but thank you for your effort. :)